# Visual Basic - How to concatenate a string in a while loop

Tags: vb.net

I've been working on a homework problem for a few hours now and cannot for the life of me figure out how to get it to work.

The premise of the program is:
-User inputs number
-Display a multiplication table from 1-9 of that users number

if they entered 4 I need to show
1 * 4 = 4
2 * 4 = 8
.
.
.
9 * 4 = 36

Here is what I (unsuccessfully) have for my loop so far:

```
Dim userNum As Integer = numInputTextBox.Text  
Dim tableDisplay As String  
Dim i As Integer = 1

Do While i <= 9    
   tableDisplay = userNum * i    
   tableTextBox.Text = tableDisplay
   i += 1
Loop
```

(tableTextBox is where the output will be stored)

The only output I get is the result of the last iteration of the loop so if I entered 7, the output I get is 63 (7 * 9)

I'm unsure how to continually add to a string and output it to the textbox while in a loop.

Any and all help is greatly appreciated. My apologies for the sloppy formatting.

Comment: `tableTextBox.Text =tableTextBox.Text &", "& tableDisplay`

Comment: Thank you, this helped a lot! The only thing I also need to do is display the calculations for each output (1* 7 = 2, new line, 2 * 7 = 14, new line, all the way until 9 * 7 = 63) ...... is there an easy way to have each calculation display on a new line and also show what went into the calculations? as above in the parentheses.

Comment: VB or VBA? populate your string variable in the loop rather than relying on the textbox, populate the string to the textbox after the loop finishes, the reason is the second time you run this it will concatenate to the previous run. vblf is Visual Basic Line Feed, you can use that like so: `MyString = "Hello" & vblf & "World"`

Answer (score 0):

Here is an idea of what I am talking about in my comment:

```
Dim userNum As Integer = numInputTextBox.Text
Dim tableDisplay As String
Dim i As Integer = 1
Do While i <= 9
    tableDisplay = userNum & " * " & i & " = " & userNum * i & vbLf
    i += 1
Loop
tableTextBox.Text = tableDisplay
```

Although I wouldn't use a while loop in this instance, I would use a for next like so:

```
Dim userNum As Integer = numInputTextBox.Text
Dim tableDisplay As String
Dim i As Integer
For i = 1 To 9
    tableDisplay = userNum & " * " & i & " = " & userNum * i & vbLf
Next
tableTextBox.Text = tableDisplay
```

Comment: Thank you so much. I was able to use the loop you provided (we havent gone over For Next yet) and with a minor tweak it works perfectly!

Comment: I would go with tableDisplay &= userNum [...] else you will only display the last calculation result...

Comment: @Martin my bad, meant to put 'Tabledisplay &' in there